# Is it possible to declare and use an anonymous function in a single statement?

Tags: c#, lambda

Is there any way to combine the following two lines into a single statement?

```
Func<XmlNode> myFunc = () => { return myNode; };
XmlNode myOtherNode = myFunc();
```

I've been trying things like the below but can't get it to work and can't determine from the documentation whether it should work or not?

```
XmlNode myOtherNode = ((Func<XmlNode>) () => { return myNode; })();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are looking to do this but ..

```
XmlNode myOtherNode = new Func<XmlNode>( () => { return myNode; } )();
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

The 'trick' is that you need to create an instance of a delegate in order for it to work, which in your example is implicity done when you do the assignment (myFunc = ...). Also, you can express your function as () => myNode to make it shorter.

```
XmlNode myOtherOne = new Func<XmlNode>( () => myNode )();
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax posted by "headsling" works.

Oddly, even though you can't use the original syntax with lambda (`=>`), you can with `delegate`:

```
XmlNode myOtherNode = ((Func<XmlNode>) delegate { return myNode; })();
```

Of course, the real question is... why? What is wrong with...

```
XmlNode myOtherNode = myNode;
```

Comment: "Of course, the real question is... why?": I want to do more within the anonymous method than just that one statement.

Comment: So refactor to a method perhaps... or whatever you're happy with.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd throw another interesting use of this construct into the mix:

```
namespace FunWithContractsAndAnonymousDelegates
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;
    using System.Linq;

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void MySort<T>(T[] array, int index, int length, IComparer<T> comparer)
        {
            Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(array != null);
            Contract.Requires<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(index >= 0 && index <= array.Length);
            Contract.Requires<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(length >= 0 && index + length <= array.Length);
            Contract.Ensures(new Func<T[], int, int, IComparer<T>, bool>((_array, _index, _length, _comparer) =>
                {
                    T[] temp = (T[])_array.Clone();
                    Array.Sort(temp, _index, _length, _comparer);
                    return temp.SequenceEqual(_array);
                })(array, index, length, comparer));

            // TODO: Replace with my heavily optimized and parallelized sort implementation...
            Array.Sort(array, index, length, comparer);
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] array = { 3, 2, 6, 1, 5, 0, 4, 7, 9, 8 };
            MySort(array, 0, array.Length, Comparer<int>.Default);
            foreach (int value in array)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Declaring and invoking an anonymous delegates means that I don't have to declare a method that I'll use only once for checking the postcondition (i.e. in the call to Contract.Ensures).

As contrived as this may look, I used this for real today...